# Latent Dirichlet Allocation with Very Specific Word and Topic Collection from Documentation

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, similarities, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Let's say I work in a company that does something and most of the time
the employees are confused about something and ask them using some
company-made apps. The thing is, most of the time, new employees are
asking the relatively same questions that maybe have answered a long
time before but they can't easily find it (it is not available on
Google too because those are company-related questions). And I'm
thinking Topic Modelling using LDA could solve this issue by analyzing
every new question, create a probability distribution from it and
compare them with all previously answered question using some
similarity function.

The thing is, there's some sort of company documentation too that can
be used as an answer source. And I need to refer them to a specific
part of the documentation which contains information related to the
question first. So every time a new question asked, it should find if
there's an answer in the documentation and if not, list any relatable
question that has been answered before as a suggestion to look up to.

My questions are

1. How do I achieve that kind of function?
2. Does LDA allow me to do both of that?
3. **Will it better if I only use word/topic that mentioned in the documentation rather than using general word/topic from something like dictionary/Wikipedia ?**

Sorry if this is a duplicate question since I don't know exactly what to search for.